# How to modify the index html in vue cli?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, indexing, vue-cli

I want to modify the index html during the vue cli build process. (vue.config.js)

**Is there any way to do this?**

This is my index html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <%= foo %>

    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico" />
    <title>blabla</title>

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=5, minimal-ui" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but tera.com-vue doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and I want vue/webpack to parse the value `1` to `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Vue will attach to the DIV with id `app`. So your `{{foo}}` will be out of range for Vue to change it.

You should look into [Single File Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html), that way you'll be able to wrap your whole HTML inside Vue.

Comment: no. I don't talk about {{}} in vue (by vue engine). just to do binding variables from webpack using vue cli.

Comment: Well you changed your source so my answer is irrelevant now. You should tag `webpack` maybe.